# How to get package changes before update in zypper

Tags: package, updates, opensuse, zypper

does a counterpart for `apt-listchanges` functionality from debian/ubuntu exists for `zypper`?

at the moment I have to do following manually for each updated package: 1) install with `zypper`, 2) check the changes with `rpm -q --changelog PACKAGE_NAME` and it is far away from the convenient way it is done by `apt-listchanges`. And most important for me, how to get changes *before* the installation (with possibility to abort)?

Comment: I still use `yast2 online_update` that does not have these problems.

Answer (score 1):

I couldn't find a way to see changes made to an individual package without downloading it. OpenSUSE collects packages in "patches" since bugs often need changes to several packages. To see what's in a patch:

- Get the name/ID of the available patches with `zypper list-patches`
- Get the info about a patch set using `zypper info -t patch $ID` where `$ID` is the ID from the output of the previous command.

If you want to look at a certain package, you can use `zypper download` to download it without installing. After that, you can use `rpm -q --changelog -p $PATH` to see the changelog of the downloaded file at `$PATH`.

Answer (score 0):

not with zypper but if you can download both rpms (old and new versions), you may use pkgdiff to check the differences.

Answer (score -1):

(I don't know what `apt-listchanges` outputs)

The main problem is to get output that is easily parsable from `zypper`. This isn't perfect, but it may get you on the way:

First get the plain names of the patches from zypper output, omitting header and trailer lines:

```
zypper -t lp | awk -F'|' '/^---/ { OK=1; next } OK && NF == 7 { gsub(" ", "", $2); print $2 }'
```

For example you could get:

```
openSUSE-2018-172
openSUSE-2018-175
openSUSE-2018-176
openSUSE-2018-178
```

Then feed that output into `zypper` again, like this:

```
zypper patch-info $(zypper -t lp | awk -F'|' '/^---/ { OK=1; next } OK && NF == 7 { gsub(" ", "", $2); print $2 }')
```

Output would include information like this (truncated for brevity):

```
Summary     : Security update for ffmpeg     
Description :                                
    This update for ffmpeg fixes the following issues:

    Updated ffmpeg to new bugfix release 3.4.2

      * Fix integer overflows, multiplication overflows, undefined
        shifts, and verify buffer lengths.
```

Comment: patch-info is not exactly what i'm looking for because it is only for "system patches", for example if i run `zypper patch-info` and see that a package `caja` will be updated i can run zypper patch-info package:caja, but it will only say that the version is outdated.

Comment: apt-listchanges downloads a package changelog from a debian server and displays it before the actual installation

Comment: OK, then use the answer that fits you better (after down-voting this). With a standard RPM repository, you cannot download the changelogs separately from the RPMs, because they are inside the RPM.